# Issue in launching Internet Explorer in Matlab Ubuntu

Tags: python, wine, playonlinux, matlab

I am trying to launch internet explorer installed using PlayonLinux through Matlab by using the command:

```
system('/usr/share/playonlinux/playonlinux --run "Internet Explorer 6"')
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
 Looking for python... 2.7.6 - wxversion(s): 2.8-gtk2-unicode
  selected
  [main] [1;34mMessage:[0m PlayOnLinux (4.2.10) is starting
  [clean_tmp] [1;34mMessage:[0m Cleaning temp directory
  (python:5148): IBUS-WARNING **: The owner of /home/muhammad/.config/ibus/bus 
 is not root!
  Script started /home/muhammad/.PlayOnLinux/shortcuts/Internet Explorer 6
  [POL_System_CheckFS] [1;34mMessage:[0m Checking filesystem for IEXPLORE.EXE
  [POL_Wine] [1;34mMessage:[0m Running wine-1.4 IEXPLORE.EXE (Working 
 directory : 
 /home/muhammad/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/InternetExplorer6/drive_c/Program Files/Internet Explorer)
 [POL_Wine] [1;34mMessage:[0m Notice: PlayOnLinux deliberately disables winemenubuilder. See 
 http://www.playonlinux.com/fr/page-26-Winemenubuilder.html
 wine: /home/muhammad/.PlayOnLinux//wineprefix/InternetExplorer6 is not owned by you
 [POL_Wine] [1;31mError:[0m Wine seems to have crashed
 If your program is running, just ignore this message
 [POL_SetupWindow_Init] [1;34mMessage:[0m Creating new window for pid 5249
 [POL_SetupWindow_Close] [1;34mMessage:[0m Closing window for pid 5249
 [POL_Wine] [1;34mMessage:[0m Wine return: 1
```

However, when I run the command using Terminal `/usr/share/playonlinux/playonlinux --run "Internet Explorer 6"`, it does not create any issue.

Please guide me how can I resolve the issue.

Comment: "/home/muhammad/.config/ibus/bus is not root!" are you running Matlab as root? Why?

Comment: And many sites will not let you visit them with IE6!

Comment: Thanks muru to highlight my mistake. I was running matlab as root. That's why the issue arises. Once I run matlab without root, issue resolved.

Can you plz also explain me why this issue occurs when running matlab as root?